# C# and MYSQL database on another computer

Tags: c#, mysql

I have developed a c sharp application that connects to a MySQL database for a uni assignment. When I submit it to be marked is it going to work on another computer? or do I need to include something to get it working on theirs?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: If depends on your server. If it is `localhost`, definitely it won't work

Comment: its just on my computer and its set to local host

Comment: So you will need to set up `locahost` on every computer where you want to use your application

Comment: ok so they would also need MySQL server installed as well then?

Comment: yes ! they need `MySQL` server and the whole `database` in it to connect and use it.

Comment: FYI you could have made your application more portable by using an embedded database http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639846/what-is-a-good-embedded-database-to-use-with-c

Comment: @mikey `MySQL` can not be embedded db

Answer (score 0):

Is the MySQL db located somewhere accessible from any public address? If so, then you only need to make sure your code points to the db's public IP instead of the local ip. If the db is not public, you will need to make sure the person running your code can get through the router, firewalls, and to your ip from wherever they are connecting.

Comment: no its local, but if I was to make it pulic, is there any good free places to store my database on. If so would I need to change the data source to point at that location?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your application to use online database, upload your database on any free web hosting server.

I personally use [000webhost.com](http://000webhost.com). But there are many. You can use any server.

You only need to change one thing. The connection to an `ip` will be provided by your server instead of `localhost`.